# nginx separate access_log file with bad status codes

Tags: nginx

I got `nginx` config file for domain `domainName.com` which write access log to file `/var/log/nginx/logName.access.log`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domainName.com;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/logName.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location ~ ^/(min/|images/|ckeditor/|img/|javascripts/|apple-touch-icon-ipad.png|apple-touch-icon-ipad3.png|apple-touch-icon-iphone.png|apple-touch-icon-iphone4.png|generated/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
          root /root/Dropbox/nodeApps/nodeJsProject/port/public; 
          access_log off;
          expires max;
        }
}
```

Is it possible to change this config file to let nginx write bad requests with http status codes `504` or `502` to separate file named for example `/var/log/nginx/bad.access.log`

```
ip - - [07/May/2014:19:28:35 +0400] "GET /url HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "http://domain.com/url" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.1003 Safari/537.36 MRCHROME SOC CHANNEL_inet2amigo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible if you don't mind to create custom error page for this errors.

```
server {
    ...
    access_log /var/log/nginx/logName.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        error_page 502 504 /50x.html;
    }

    ...

    location = /50x.html {
        internal;
        root /root/Dropbox/nodeApps/nodeJsProject/port/public;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/bad.access.log;
    }
}
```

And you will need to have file `/root/Dropbox/nodeApps/nodeJsProject/port/public/50x.html`.

Comment: this method works only if `node.js` site stopped on port 9000. If it is running it makes response with own `node.js` `50x` page and so `bad.access.log` keeps clean.